# How to configure connection to service with SSL Certificate when using not apache service. SOS

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, ssl, certificate, port

I am an University student. And today I am dealing with different web services. I am using apache2 service for starting page and running it with my letencrypt certificate and all works perfect. But my apache redirect user to ReactJs service on another port (:3000) i am use https connection also, but on this port my valid certificate gone and React use some self-signed certificate. How i read in google, react can't use SSL and i must somehow configure apache to serve this port with valid SSL, maybe i am wrong. SOS guys

So my question is:

How i can setup valid SSL for my ReactJS app on :3000 port?
How i can even setup certificate for another ports than apache?
Is it possible somehow run ReactJs with SSL?(i am using HTTPS=true npm start)

I Hope somebody can help me, i am already spent all day looking and reading. No answers at all.

Is it possible to configure valid certificate to an HTTPS acceptable ReactJs service?

P.S By the way i am using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Virtual Machine.

Comment: I think this question might be off topic here, as it is not directly programming related. Maybe https://askubuntu.com/ or https://serverfault.com/ are better places for this question.